# circular model of x-axis in simulink with virtual reality

Tags: matlab, model, geometry, simulink, virtual-reality

I designed a circular path model in Simulink, however I want to rotate object e.g ball along **X-Axis** but it rotates along **Y-axis** by default. How can I do this by **VR SIGNAL EXPANDER** or editing in **Virtual Reality**?
**the thing i want to model a spiral in which the object starting from bottom and moves towards up.**
I have model in which:
[image]

*

> A clock connected to two trigonometry function of **Sin** and **Cos** which
>   makes their separate product by taking **Sin** value and clock value and
>   similarly as **Cos**, And Mux-ing their two generated signals with a third
>   clock signal in order to increase its circular path. I can't use **VR
>   SIGNAL EXPANDER** as there are 3 multiplexed signals doesn't support
>   that and also, the final translation requires 3 signals, so without
>   **VR SIGNAL EXPANDER** it works but only along **Y-axis**.

*

My virtual reality wrl :

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8

#Created with V-Realm Builder v2.0
#Integrated Data Systems Inc.
#www.ids-net.com


SpotLight {
    cutOffAngle 0.785398
    direction   0 -0.995037 -0.0995036
    location    0 30 0
    on  TRUE
}
Background {
    groundAngle [ 0.9, 1.5, 1.57 ]
    groundColor [ 0 0.8 0,
              0.174249 0.82 0.187362,
              0.467223 0.82 0.445801,
              0.621997 0.67 0.600279 ]
    skyAngle    [ 0.1, 1.2, 1.57 ]
    skyColor    [ 0.76238 0.8 0.1427,
              0.277798 0.219779 0.7,
              0.222549 0.390234 0.7,
              0.60094 0.662637 0.69 ]
}
Viewpoint {
    jump    TRUE
    position    0 10 40
    description "My_View"
}
DEF Ball Transform {
    translation -0.3753 13.4729 -10
    scale   1.5 1.5 1.5
    children Shape {
        appearance  Appearance {
            material    Material {
                diffuseColor    0.8 0.471841 0.503074
                emissiveColor   0.35 0.237062 0.271762
                specularColor   0.45 0.282414 0.308843
            }

        }

        geometry    Sphere {
            radius  1.5
        }

    }
}
Transform {
    translation 0 -0.1 0
    children Shape {
        appearance  Appearance {
            material    Material {
            }

            texture ImageTexture {
                url "texture/Brick_2.jpg"
            }

        }

        geometry    Box {
            size    20 0.1 20
        }

    }
}
DEF Top_View Viewpoint {
    fieldOfView 0.785398
    jump    TRUE
    orientation -1 0 0  0.753982
    position    0 34.6716 22.3133
    description "Top_View"
}
```